# Exposing SignalR websockets from mcr aspnet WebAPI Container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, websocket

I am trying to run an ASP .NET (WebAPI, NOT Core) application inside a container and expose the websocket. It seems like everything should 'just work' but I'm having quite a time making that happen. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-20200714-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature Web-WebSockets

COPY package\\contents\\www /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY api\\Web.config /inetpub/wwwroot
```

I got desperate and added the RUN statement. No change.

I just upgraded the project's nugets to the latest SignalR libs (only two minor versions forward).

I know it is a container issue because I am running CONTAINER and BARE on the same box. From my machine I am doing:

```
$> wscat -c 'wss://CONTAINER/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&..'
error: Unexpected server response: 400

$> wscat -c 'wss://BARE/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&..'
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I should mention the non-websocket parts of the application work well under both scenarios. Unfortunately the serverSentEvents fallback will not work for my use case. It must be able to negotiate a socket connection.

Any thoughts on what else I could check out? Has anyone had luck running a socket from an aspnet (NOT Core) container?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made a mistake when deploying the container, and had posted essentially the same version of the code. When I said: "I just upgraded the project's nugets to the latest SignalR libs (only two minor versions forward)." that was an accurate statement, but the results of such were never realized. After I got the updated libs posted I can confirm the socket connection is restored.

Ultimately a SignalR upgrade fixed the problem.